# How do I get the line numbers back in Dreamweaver CS4?

Tags: dreamweaver

I let my friend use it and now it's gone.

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Select View > Code View Options

Answer (score 0):

NB - View -> Code View Options -> Line Numbers also works on CS6 as that's what I came here to find out.

I know this is an old thread but cheers Art W